# Can't hide .html extensions in URL, something wrong with my htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, hide

Not sure if it's server side but I can't seem to hide .html from my sites URLs, did I do something wrong?

```
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^vid/?$   /x2.html
RewriteRule ^img/?$   /x2.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://site/error.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://site/error.html
```

Comment: Looks ok-ish, though it is not absolutely clear what you are trying to do. Have you checked that your dynamic configuration file is evaluated _at all_ ? How?

Comment: I'm trying to make my urls cleaner by removing the .html extensions so no more WWW.SITE.COM/PHOTOS.HTML.

I'm assuming it's server side since I'm using a new free host I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: Which just repeats what you already wrote instead of answering to my simple question....